# stimulsoft report doesnt update the report

Tags: c#, winforms, stimulsoft

I have a combobox with list of customers, when choose a specific customer and make a query and send it to stimulsoft to create a report, it works correctly, but when I close the report and choose another customer the report still show the previous customer's report and does not update it.
until I close the form and reopen it, and choose other customer but when I choose another customer it it doesn't works correctly again.

```
var results = (from x in asdb.TblCustomers
                           where x.CustID == (int)rddCustName.SelectedValue
                           select x).ToList();

            stiSpecCust.Load("Reports//SpecCustM.mrt");
            stiSpecCust.RegBusinessObject("DT", "DT", results);
            stiSpecCust.Render();
            stiSpecCust.Show();
```

Comment: Have you tried to `stiSpecCust.Dictionary.DataSources.Clear() ` before the RegBusinessObject and `stiSpecCust.Dictionary.Synchronize()` after?

Comment: it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

we must add this before RegBusinessObject :

```
stiSpecCust.BusinessObjectsStore.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
after path the parameters do this

```
 stiSpecCust.Compile();
 stiSpecCust.Render();
 stiSpecCust.Show();
```

you need compile before  render it